# Action Script 3. After clicking button set It to "selected" state

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript, imagebutton

I have created button with different up, over, down and hit images. Up, over and down states working correctly, just "hit" states don't work. I mean after button is clicked, It return to "Up" state, not holing in "Hit" state. What's the problem?

I've tried:

`my_btn.selected = true;` - doesn't helped.

`my_btn.downState;` - doesn't helped too.

`my_btn.enabled = false;` - this disable button, but still show button's "Up" state.

Could you help me, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hit 'state' is actually used as a hitting area, which means that whatever you draw there, it will be used just as a mask for where the button is CLICKABLE.

The standard flash button does not have a 'selected' state. Maybe you need to skin a button component or create your own.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have already created my own button with my images. What do you mean to create my own button?

Comment: I meant to implement the functionality of a button in your own class. This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497342/how-to-create-a-reusable-toggle-button-in-as3

Comment: Could you help me to do that?

Comment: Just updated my comment. Visit the link and check out the code. You need to link that class as a linkage to the item in the library (right click, properties).